# Calling a service running in a docker container from an angular2 app

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, angular2-services

I have a UI application which is developed in Angular2. I also have a couple of services that are developed in Spring Boot. I am trying to call a Spring Boot service from the Angular application.

Below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
networks:
  mynet:
services:
  ui:
    image: uiimg
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
  srvc:
    image: scservice
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  testsrvc:
    image: testsrvc
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

This is how I am calling the service defined by "srvc" from angular.

```
return this.http.get("http://srvc:8080/test").map(result => result.json());
```

But I am getting the error 
    srvc:8080/test Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

However, I can call http://srvc:8080/test from another service in "testsrvc" without any issues.

My understanding is that since the UI request originates from the browser, it has no means of knowing what "srvc" is, whereas since "testsrvc" also runs in a container, it can link to "srvc"

So how should I be calling "srvc" from angular?

P.S: I tried http://srvc:8080/test and http://srvc/test
Neither is working.

The angular application in the container is up and running and I am able to access it from http://localhost:4200

Comment: When I call the services using localhost from the angular app, it is working. Is this the right way to do? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, did you by any chance solve this?

Comment: You will need the angular app to call a backend service which is running on nodejs or something in the same server as the angular app and then from the node js app make calls to whatever other services you have in your docker compose using the service name, Hope that helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The angular application in the container is up and running and I am able to access it from http://localhost:4200

this is the correct way of accessing the container from your host machine.

if you wanted to use `http://srvc:8000`, you would have to be inside of a Docker container in the same Docker network. your docker-compose configuration has this set up correctly, so you could access that network name and port from within one of your other docker containers.

but from your host machine, you don't have access to the network names of the containers. mapping the port allows you to access the service in the container through `localhost`, as you are seeing.

your other option, if you need your host to be able to see `srvc` as a proper name, is to edit your `hosts` file and add an entry for that. just map `srvc` to `127.0.0.1` and then you will be able to use `http://srvc:8000` from your host machine, and it will route to localhost:8000.

Comment: How do I access `http://srvc:8000` in my angular app inside container? I have similar situation but I am not able access it even inside the container