# Cannot access nodejs + express backend container from frontend angular + nginx container

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have 2 apps, the first one was made using Node + Express, and the second one with Angular. I am using Docker (with docker compose), i actually have 3 containers, `backend`, `frontend` and `mongodb`, check out my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:5.0.5-focal
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ******
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: *********
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    container_name: backend
    image: backend:v1.0
    env_file:
      - ./backend/config.env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    image: frontend:v1.0
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

The `Dockerfile` of the different apps are inside specific folder (they are working correct). I executed the command to inspect the default network created by Docker on `docker compose up` like this `docker inspect default_coal` and i got the following output:

```
[
    {
        ... some other config
        "Containers": {
            "0814190f3d6045a0cd7e0b26194ad3dc3ad2dcc87fa9cd04521002cad01b0e0c": {
                "Name": "frontend",
                "EndpointID": "1562c6c2b803d62f0057425e7dc60492e0f75a1d3059cce44001c747755cd512",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "5d0287c5b57b0d15a74952df2f69fc4655a32c88eebfdfdf2462f02083a0e86e": {
                "Name": "backend",
                "EndpointID": "a99618bf8dd48f01ee36b4fe94a8e26ae3ea9169385a7195fa13876758aa2b3e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a77a36054248301c7c20490795b59ede19cb997a4f1de26f9264adb549593e40": {
                "Name": "mongodb",
                "EndpointID": "dbc0777ff8811b4500185779b0778647e8b0715f7721e1924e366b4745173807",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "coal",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.2.3"
        }
    }
]
```

I read a lot of docs and i know i can access another container in the same network using its container name, so, in the Angular enviroment file, i have the following URL to access the backend from `frontend` container to `backend` container:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  API: 'http://backend:3000',
};
```

It is supposed to work, but it does not. When the frontend makes some request to the backend it keeps the `backend` word and does not replace it with the backend container ip or something. So, i am getting an error due to this.

Comment: The Angular application isn't running inside a container.  The `frontend` container serves its code, but the actual application is running in your browser, and can't use Docker networking.  See for example [How to connect frontend to backend via docker-compose networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879017/how-to-connect-frontend-to-backend-via-docker-compose-networks) or [Calling a service running in a docker container from an angular2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006620/calling-a-service-running-in-a-docker-container-from-an-angular2-app).

Comment: I am really thankful my friend, i just changed from `backend` to `localhost` and it is working!